# Counting Matching Cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have 3 columns (A, B, C)

Columns A & B contain numbers -- each row containing a single digit, 1 through 6 (the numbers on a set of dice).

I need to figure out how many times Column's A & B match at the same time, for each specific set of matching dice numbers.

For example, matching dice can match these numbers (also called the "Hard Ways") 
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,6

I need Excel to count how many times 1,1 occurred separate from when 2,2 occurred, and 3,3 and so on...

Any idea on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your pairs all have a 1 in 36 chance of happening. Any other pair has a 1 in 18 chance of happening. What is it exactly you want to do? And what is in column C?

Comment: Column A/B are Dice 1 and Dice 2 results. Column C is the total. So 2, 2 would be 4 for Column C. All I want to do is calculate the number of hardways that are actually recorded in Column A/B and enter it into a cell (For each specific set).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in D1 and copy it down the column:
    =if(A1 = B1, A1, 0)
Then write 1 to 6 in column F (F1 to F6)
Use the following in G1 and copy it down the column to G6:
    =Countif(D:D, F1)

Comment: I built my formulas assuming no title rows. Should you need to start from another row, all references to row 1 would need to be changed to your starting row. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT. See screenshot
[image]